# How to create dataframe with single header ( 1 row many cols) and update values to this dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a dataframe in pyspark like the table below :

```
category|   category_id|    bucket| prop_count| event_count |   accum_prop_count |  accum_event_count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nation  |   nation     |    1     | 222       |     444     |   555              |  6677
```

So, the code I tried below :

```
   schema = StructType([])
   df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
   df = df.withColumn("category",F.lit('nation')).withColumn("category_id",F.lit('nation')).withColumn("bucket",bucket)

   df = df.withColumn("prop_count",prop_count).withColumn("event_count",event_count).withColumn("accum_prop_count",accum_prop_count).withColumn("accum_event_count",accum_event_count)
   df.show()
```

This is giving an error :

**AssertionError: col should be Column**

Also, The values of the columns have to be updated again later and the update will also be of 1 line.

How to do this??

Comment: Are `bucket`, `even_count`, `accum_prop_count` , `accum_event_count` python object of type integer? If so they are not spark columns, and you'll need to use `F.lit()`

Comment: why do you need an empty dataframe here. ? you have all your row values and they can be used to create the dataframe, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is lies in lines where you are using variables like `.withColumn("bucket",bucket)`. You are trying to create a new column by giving an integer value. `withColumn` expects a column and not a single integer value.

To solve this, you can use the `lit` just like you are already using for "nation"

like :

```
df = df\
.withColumn("category",F.lit('nation'))\
.withColumn("category_id",F.lit('nation'))\
.withColumn("bucket",F.lit(bucket))\
.withColumn("prop_count",F.lit(prop_count))\
.withColumn("event_count",F.lit(event_count))\
.withColumn("accum_prop_count",F.lit(accum_prop_count))\
.withColumn("accum_event_count",F.lit(accum_event_count))
```

another simple and cleaner way to write it may be like this :

```
# create schema
fields = [StructField("category", StringType(),True),
          StructField("category_id", StringType(),True),
          StructField("bucket", IntegerType(),True),
          StructField("prop_count", IntegerType(),True),
          StructField("event_count", IntegerType(),True),
          StructField("accum_prop_count", IntegerType(),True)
         ]
schema = StructType(fields)

# load data
data = [["nation","nation",1,222,444,555]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()
```